# batch mode with promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I need to process a lot of data. For each entry of the data, we need to submit query to mysql. my current solution is like following:

```
    var Q = require('q');
    function process(entry){
        ...
        var defered=Q.defer();
        connection.query(sql,defered.makeNodeResolver());
        return defered.promise;
    }
    function ProcessAll(results ) {
        var waitfor=[];
        for( var i=0;i< results.length;i++){
            waitfor.push( process(results[i]));
        }
        Q.all(waitfor).then(function(results) {
            notifySuc(results);
        },function(results){
            notifyFail(results);
        });
    }
```

However when the number of the data is huge, it will crash due to out of memory:

```
FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of memory

 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x109624c [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportApiFailure(char const*, char const*) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 6: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, char const*, char const*, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
```

How can I break it with smaller batches? For example, we can process 1000 entries each time. After they are all one we resume the rest. How to do so with the callback functions?

In addition, can we make multiple entries get processed in parallel?

Comment: Are you sure you need to submit multiple queries to the db? Is it not possible to make one big query and then process the results of that query?

Comment: `can we make multiple entries get processed in parallel` - erm ... they are processed in parallel (as much as can be with javascript) ... your code is firing of as many `connection.query` as there are elements in the array ..

Comment: I can't combine multiple queries into one, because the data is big. If I have 100k entries, for each entry I need to write 1K byte query, the combined 100M query would be too big to submit to the database. Besides, the main purpose to break into small batch, say 1k each, is that I only need the memory for the 1K entries at each time, instead of load all the 100M at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [BaconJS](https://baconjs.github.io/api.html) to do this. You can create an event stream with **Bacon.fromPromise(promise [, abort] [, eventTransformer])** and then use **stream.bufferWithCount(count)** to break your processing up into batches. **BaconJS** is a small Functional Reactive Programming Library. To learn more about FRP, you can read the [The Introduction to FRP](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) for a quick primer.

Answer (score 0):

If the error isn't due to `notifySuc` you can easily process a batch at a time as follows

```
var Q = require('q');
function process(entry){
    ...
    var defered=Q.defer();
    connection.query(sql,defered.makeNodeResolver());
    return defered.promise;
}
function processBatch(batch) {
    return Q.all(batch.map(item => process(item)));
}
function ProcessAll(results) {
    var batchSize = 1000;
    var pos = 0;
    var promises = Q([]); // initial promise of empty array
    while (pos < results.length) {
        (function(pos) {
            promises = promises.then(result => processBatch(results.slice(pos, batchSize)).then(results => result.concat(results)));
        })(pos);
        pos += batchSize;
    }
    promises.then(function(results) {
        notifySuc(results);
    },function(results){
        notifyFail(results);
    });
}
```

Comment: it seems when results.slice get called synchoronously, pos is already reached results.length. Thus the processBatch is always passed an empty array.

Comment: ahhh poop ... forgot my IIFE :p